# Por qué cuando le paso un año no bisiesto me lo evalua como bisiesto igualmente?

Tags: java, switch

La idea es usando la funcion esBisiesto(int año) usar un switch para pasarle por teclado un mes y un año y me diga cuantos días tiene ese mes. Sin embargo, solo consigo que me devuelva que febrero tiene 29 días, nunca me devuelve que tiene 28 aun pasandole un año no bisiesto (como por ejemplo 2001). No entiendo por qué.

Corto el código porque el resto de meses no tiene ninguna cosa especial, solo me interesa que si es bisiesto me diga que febrero tiene 29 días y si no es bisiesto que tiene 28 días. Gracias.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DíasDelMes {
    public static boolean esBisiesto (int año) {
        if (año % 4 == 0 && año % 100 != 0 && año % 400 == 0  ) {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Introduce un mes");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mes = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un año");     
        int año = sc.nextInt();
        switch(mes) {
                            case 1: mes = 1;
                            System.out.println("Enero tiene 31 días");
                            break;
                            case 2: mes = 2;
                            if (esBisiesto(año)){
                            System.out.println("Febrero tiene 29 días");}
                            else System.out.println("Febrero tiene 28 días");
                            break;
                            case 3: mes = 3;
                            System.out.println("Marzo tiene 31 días");
                            break;
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un método esBisiesto

```
public static boolean esBisiesto (int año) {
        if (año % 4 == 0 && año % 100 != 0 && año % 400 == 0  ) {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Si se cumple la condición del if, retorna true. Si no se cumple... retorna true.

Hay algún caso en esa función que devuelva false? :) Yo le diría que, si la condición del IF no se cumple, retorne false (porque salió del IF sin retornar, no entró, no se cumplieron las condiciones de *bisiestidad* (término totalmente inventado, por supuesto)

```
public static boolean esBisiesto (int año) {
    if ( año % 4 == 0 && año % 100 != 0 && año % 400 == 0  ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: pero si se cumplen las condiciones retorna true por tanto si no se cumplen ya no retorna true, entonces por defecto devolveria false no?

Comment: @Edw DONDE DICE RETURN FALSE? Si no se cumplen, sale del if... y devuelve true por el segundo return!!! No existe tal cosa como "por defecto"; debes decirle qué retornar, el compilador se va a quejar si hay un flujo de ejecución por el que no retornes algo explícitamente. ¿Dónde viste que hay "retorno por defecto"?

Comment: Tiene todo el sentido del mundo lo que dices, sin embargo, tras mucho probar sigo sin ser capaz de modificarlo de forma correcta,que desastre...

Comment: @Edw Respuesta editada. Sugiero un repaso a cómo funcionan las estucturas de control en Java. Sugiero también que cuando digas "probé mucho" siempre indiques qué es todo lo que probaste para guiarte y que entiendas qué está pasando.

Comment: me apunto sus sugerencias en mi cuaderno que de seguro me serán útiles. Si me permite, yo tambien le sugiero que repase los operadores lógicos, puesto que el error se encontraba allí (además de lo que usted decía de devolver el false, por supuesto) (if ((año % 4 == 0) && (año % 100) != 0 || (año % 400 == 0)) -> aquí erradicaba parte del error.

Comment: Heh, el criterio para validar no hacía diferencia si la función siempre devuelve true. Que bueno que revisaste tu validación y encontraste el problema y gracias por la sugerencia pero yo los operadores los tengo clarísimos (que no me interesara la condición por el problema obvio, eso es diferente)!

Answer (score 1):

A partir de java 8 puedes usar la clase [YearMonth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) del paquete `java.time.` para saber cuantos días tiene un mes en un año determinado de una forma más elegante.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un mes");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mes = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un año");     
        int anio = sc.nextInt();
        
        //obtenemos una instancia de YearMonth de un año y mes
        YearMonth anioMes= YearMonth.of(anio, mes);
        //obtenemos cuantos días tiene el mes
        int diasEnNes=anioMes.lengthOfMonth(); 
                
        switch(mes) {
            case 1:                
            System.out.println("Enero tiene "+diasEnNes+" días");
            break;
            case 2: 
            System.out.println("Febrero tiene "+diasEnNes+" días");
            break;
            case 3: 
            System.out.println("Marzo tiene "+diasEnNes+" días");
            break;
        }                    
    }
```

**Observación**
No uses la letra `ñ` en la declaración de variables, contantes.